# CSS - Show Entire Image as Background Without Cropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to setup a div with a background image with some text on top of it. The background image needs to stretch the entire width of the viewport, which I've been able to do successfully. This is my CSS:

```
.intro-header {
  padding-top: 50px; 
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it isn't showing the full height of the image. The image is being cropped at the top and bottom.  I want the image to show it's full height and the user needs to be able to scroll down to see more content below the image.

Is there a way I can show the full image without cutting the top and bottom off?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `background-size: 100% 100%;` instead of `cover`.

Comment: I was able to get it working using this and removing fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the fixed and instead of `cover` use `contain`. If you want a specific size though I would define a height in my css.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `background-size: auto 100%;`

I updated an example in fiddle to see how its looks.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ozmn00t/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.intro-header {
    padding-top: 50px; 
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(http://);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

setting the width and height of background-size to 100% will fill the div

Comment: That doesn't preserve the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fixed from the background.

```
url() no-repeat center center
```