# show full width and height the image-background

Tags: css

It may seem like a repeated question, but in my case nothing has worked.
I want to put a picture inside a `div` and show it completely until it is possible. my image is a rectangle with edges in the corners, I would like it to be seen inside the `div` according to the size of the div.

[image]

```css
    .container_img{
       border:1px solid red;
       margin-top:-14px;
       display: table; 
       margin-top:2px; 
       width: 709px; 
       height: 141px;     
       background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/VBOZfaY.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container_img"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86avtx54/

Comment: `background-size: contain`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Show Entire Image as Background Without Cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261267/css-show-entire-image-as-background-without-cropping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `background-size: 100% 100%;`. See the code snippet below

```css
   .container_img{
       border:1px solid red;
       margin-top:-14px;
       display: table; 
       margin-top:2px; 
       width: 709px; 
       height: 141px;     
       background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/VBOZfaY.png");
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container_img"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

check it out..might help you..

```css
<style>
.container_img{
   border:1px solid red;
   margin-top:2px; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%;     
  
   }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container_img">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/VBOZfaY.png">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]